# How can I use prefetch_related to get the name field of objects with ForeignKey relationships?

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    A = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name="links")
    name = models.CharField()
```

In my template I would like to print out the 'name' of each object associated to each ModelA object via ForeignKey, I am doing so like this

```
{% for a in modela_list %}
 <p>{{ a.name }} </p>
    {% for link in modela_list.links.all % }
        <p>Link name: {{ link.name }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

While this does work, from what I understand it is incredibly inefficient, and very slow. How can I use prefetch_related to make this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
modela_list = ModelA.objects.prefetch_related('links').filter(...)
```

Then send it to your context.